# PostgreSQL insert data always fail process hang up

Tags: postgresql

When i want insert a row to table.
It always hangs on waiting can not commit successful.

```
postgres 17941  2092  0 16:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
postgres 17943 17941  0 16:42 ?        00:00:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
postgres 17944 17941  0 16:42 ?        00:00:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
postgres 17945 17941  0 16:42 ?        00:00:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
postgres 17946 17941  0 16:42 ?        00:00:00 postgres: stats collector process                                                                                           
postgres 18326 17941  0 16:51 ?        00:00:00 postgres: admin gt_development 127.0.0.1(40309) COMMIT waiting for 0/1217CA98
```

Who can help me?

Comment: This should be helpful: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring and this: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_dependency_information

Comment: It looks from that process status that it is waiting until WAL records are written to disk (and maybe also sent to one or more standby servers). Do you have standby servers?

Comment: Examine the PostgreSQL server log files to see if there are any useful / informative messages there. You should also check `dmesg` or your operating system kernel error log to see if there are any I/O errors or file system errors reported. Please edit your question with this information and then comment here once you have done so, since that will notify other people of the eidt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reply.

I have fixed by pure reinstall the postgresql 9.1